# OpenCV with Android 4.0 and NDK r8d not working

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I am new to OpenCV and android NDK . To begin with a sample NDK program, i wrote an activity having a native function and implemented it and it works fine.
I am able to build and run it successfully.

But when in the CPP file, i insert the following header:-

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
```

i am getting a build error on eclipse as :-
**E:/software\java\android_adt\OpenCV-2.4.3.2-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:56:21: fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make:**  [obj/local/armeabi/objs/OpenCVTest/OpenCVTest.o] Error 1*

Here is my java file:-

```
package com.example.opencvtest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class OpenCVMain extends Activity {

    public final String TAG = "OPENCVLOG";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG,"loading the library OpenCVTest.so");
        System.loadLibrary("OpenCVTest");
        Log.i(TAG,"Loaded the library successfully");
        TextView t =  new TextView(this);
        t.setText(nativeDemo());
        setContentView(t);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_open_cvmain);
    }

    public native String nativeDemo();

}
```

JNI cpp file:-

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>


extern "C"
{

jstring Java_com_example_opencvtest_OpenCVMain_nativeDemo(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
}

jstring Java_com_example_opencvtest_OpenCVMain_nativeDemo(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj)
{
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello Native !!!!");
}
```

Android.mk file:-

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := OpenCVTest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := OpenCVTest.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

please guide me where am i making the mistake while importing the OpenCV header file.
Also, the "algorithm" file, i can access in eclipse when i am doing a CTRL+click on the "algorithm" file in core.hpp line 56.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create an "**Application.mk**" file?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15129570/1368342) might help.