# Compiling code with OpenCV dependency Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to compile C++ code dependent on OpenCV on the Android NDK. 
I have looked into several answers (mainly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054666/opencv-on-android-headers-no-such-file-directory/15129570#15129570)) but apparently the NDK still cannot see the directory I'm giving it in the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES variable.

This is my Application.mk:

```
APP_ABI :=armeabi armeabi-v7a
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_PLATFORM :=android-14
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.7
```

This is my Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= swt
LOAL_CPP_EXTENSIO:=.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /usr/include:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/sys:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/gnu:/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm:/home/hamdy/Downloads/android-ndk-r8e/sources:/usr/local/include/opencv:/usr/local/include/opencv2/core
LOCAL_CFLAFS := -x c++ -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := TextDetection.cpp FeaturesMain.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is the error I'm getting [cv.h is the file included in my .cpp so it can apparently see that in the /usr/local/include/opencv directory but cannot get past the includes in it]:

```
/usr/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:33: fatal error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but when I've compiled the same under Linux everything compiled fine. Under Windows there were errors. So I've switched to Linux

Comment: It's pretty strange to me that this isn't running on Linux easily too :/

Comment: I did compile OpenCV examples, those that come with the OpenCV for Android SDK, under LInux cleanly.