# Can't compile android project wiht JNI code (algorithm not found)

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to build simple android app with some JNI code.
I already try this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15054666/opencv-on-android-headers-no-such-file-directory/15129570#15129570), but isn't help

When I press build project in eclipse I get this error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
fatal error: algorithm: No such file or directory   Tracker     line 56, external location: /home/slani/code/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp  C/C++ Problem
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/detect_jni/detect_jni.o] Error 1  Tracker         C/C++ Problem
```

Line 56 in core.hpp contains the relevant include.

This is my Android.mk file jni folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include /home/slani/code/OpenCV-2.4.6-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE    := detect_jni
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := detect_jni.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

This is my Aplication.mk file in jni folder:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

This is my .cpp file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>

using namespace cv;

extern "C"{
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_slani_tracker_OpenCamera_findObject((JNIEnv *env, jlong addRgba, jlong addHsv);
    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_slani_tracker_OpenCamera_findObject((JNIEnv *env, jlong addRgba, jlong addHsv)
    {

        Mat& rgba = *(Mat*)addRgba;
        Mat& hsv = *(Mat*)addHsv;

        cvtColor(rgba, hsv,CV_RGBA2HSV);

    }
}
```

[image: This is path to my ndk-build]

[image: This is my path and symbols in eclipse]

Can someone please help me? What could be causing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Thomas thanks for your help.  I find my mistake

my name of Application.mk file was Aplication.mk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my [answer at your thread in answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/23295/i-cant-compile-jni-file/?answer=23323#post-id-23323)

Should help